# npm stopped working after running npm kill in terminal

Tags: npm

My Node and npm were working perfectly fine, but yesterday I ran a command `npm kill` in my terminal accidentally, now I cannot run `npm start` or `npm install` from my terminal. I am getting the error like shown.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/winniethomas/Bootcamp/instructor/UBHM-VIRT-FSF-PT-09-2022-U-LOLC/22-State/01-Activities/25-Ins_Actions-Reducers/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/winniethomas/Bootcamp/instructor/UBHM-VIRT-FSF-PT-09-2022-U-LOLC/22-State/01-Activities/25-Ins_Actions-Reducers/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I have tried running:

- `npm install`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install -g npm`

but not working and giving error with code `! code EACCES`
and also running `sudo chown -R` but nothing helps